# Calculating ages based on birthdates

Tags: r, datetime, data-manipulation

***Sample***

```
 df <- data.frame(
  Birth_Date = c("1952-03-21", "1963-12-20", "1956-02-25", "1974-08-04", "1963-06-13", "1956-11-20", "1974-03-07", "1963-10-23", "1952-11-24", "1974-12-16"),
  Items_Amount = c(68,189,69,19,299,79,149,149,29,189)
  )
df
```

I'm trying to analyse a data-set, which has column Item_Amount(in $) and customer's birth-date spread across 90 years. Goal is to compare the sales percentage based on suitable age groups.

The main data frame contains date "BirthDate" column from "1902-02-13" to "1991-12-11" as dates not string

```
'data.frame':   350241 obs. of  1 variable:
$ BirthDate: Date, format: "1964-06-08" "1964-06-08" "1964-06-08" "1964-06-08" ...


>  min(Trans_Cust$Birth_Date)
[1] "1902-02-13"

> difftime(max(Trans_Cust$Birth_Date),min(Trans_Cust$Birth_Date),units = "auto")
Time difference of 32808 days

> max(Trans_Cust$Birth_Date)
[1] "1991-12-11"
```

How Do I find the present ages based on "Birth_Date" column, store it to new column "Present_ages" and then proceed with calculating `sum(Items_Amount)` grouped by present_ages.

Comment: Make sure you provide [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when asking for help. What exactly is the desired output here? What do you want to do with these decades?

Comment: @MrFlick Details added

Comment: Your modified question refers to agegroup01 - agegroup09  but your description of the data says that your data spans 10 decades.

Comment: I assuming agegroup01 as 1st quantile of decade 1 from "1902-02-13" to "1912-02-12"

so that  "1902-02-13" to "1991-12-11" will have somewhat 9 quantiles

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous.

Comment: Don't post pictures of data. See how to create a reproducible dataset in the question itself at the link i previously provided.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your birth dates are just strings, so you need to convert them to some form of date.  I am using `POSIXct`. Once converted,  you can just set up the decade boundaries and use `cut` to break the dates into groups.

```
BirthDate = c("1964-06-08", "1964-06-08", "1964-06-08", "1964-06-08",
         "1902-02-13", "1991-12-11", "1944-06-06", "1929-10-24")
StartDecade = seq(as.POSIXct("1900-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2000-01-01"), by="10 years")
cut(as.POSIXct(BirthDate), breaks=StartDecade)
[1] 1960-01-01 1960-01-01 1960-01-01 1960-01-01 1900-01-01 1990-01-01 1940-01-01 1920-01-01
```

It may be prettier to simplify the names

```
as.numeric(cut(as.POSIXct(BirthDate), breaks=StartDecade)) - 1
[1] 6 6 6 6 0 9 4 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.
I have edited question details, Can you look it once again and help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a numeric value "rounded" to the decade:

```
BirthDate = as.Date(c("1964-06-08", "1964-06-08", "1964-06-08", "1964-06-08", "1902-02-13", "1991-12-11", "1944-06-06", "1929-10-24"))

 BDdecade <- round( as.numeric( format(BirthDate, "%Y"))-5, -1)
 BDdecade
#[1] 1960 1960 1960 1960 1900 1990 1940 1920
```

Needed to extract the year, convert to numeric and subtract 5, since the `floor` function does not have the same capacity for rounding to tens and hundreds as does `round`.

It wasn't clear what your desired starting point for the "decades was supposed to be. This would split on the basis of the minimum date.

```
> BDdecade2 <- cut(BirthDate, breaks= seq( min(BirthDate), max(BirthDate), by= "10 years"))
> BDdecade2
[1] 1962-02-13 1962-02-13 1962-02-13 1962-02-13 1902-02-13 <NA>       1942-02-13
[8] 1922-02-13
8 Levels: 1902-02-13 1912-02-13 1922-02-13 1932-02-13 1942-02-13 ... 1972-02-13
```

The NA suggest you might need to add `+365` (or perhaps even more) to the max date.